# Script should output this text "this is text ";" Nano ";" more than 10 characters

Tags: linux, shell, redhat

I am using Linux RedHat 4-5

```
Unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
```

How to implement the output correctly below?
here is my wrong conclusion:

```
dima@localhost ~]$ ./myscript11.txt dijdq uirh riouhr
"dijdq";"n
```

Script:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "\"${1}\";\"nano\";\"more then 10 symbols\"| head -n 1 | cut -c -10
```

script will output the text provided as an argument, the name of the editor used to create the file and whether or not the text is longer then 10 symbols on the same line divided by semicolons and surrounded by double quotes (e.g. some script this is text should output "this is text"; "nano"; "more then 10 symbols").

Comment: The quotes aren't matched because you escaped the last doublequote.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: If you want the last double quote to be shown literally, you need another double quote after it.

Comment: quotes already found, necessary,   need to add something to output "this is text"; "nano"; "more then 10 symbols"). here is my conclusion: dima@localhost ~]$ ./myscript11.txt dijdq uirh riouhr
"dijdq";"n

Comment: above added my wrong conclusion

Comment: The error is still because you're missing the double quote after `symbols\"`

Comment: What do you mean by "wrong conclusion"? Is that your expected output, or is it the wrong output?